# Vuejs Invalid v-for expression as array element does not exist?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So there is an `Error compiling template` error.

It seems though Vue is trying to access an array element that does not exist. That is `recommendationResponse[recommendedItems]` in the below code.

The exact error is `Invalid v-for expression:`recommendationResponse[recommendedItems] as item`

I thought that portion would not be rendered as the `v-if` would fail on initialisation. Nonetheless I don't think I am doing good enough checking if that array element exists.

The code is:

```
<div v-if="recommendationResponse" class="row">
        <h2>Response</h2>
        <div class="well">
            {{ recommendationResponse }}
        </div>
        <div v-for="recommendationResponse[recommendedItems] as item" class="col-md-4">
            <h4>{{ item['items'][0]['id'] }}</h4>
            <p>{{ item['items'][0]['name'] }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Vue Instance**:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        recommendationResponse: ''
    },
    methods: {
        getRecommendations: function(event) {
            this.recommendationResponse = json data I get from somewhere                
        }
    },
```

Comment: It still has to parse the template and the error is explicit. That is not a valid v-for expression. Maybe you want `item in recommendationResponse['recommendedItems']`?

Comment: Thanks. quite a silly error on this one. Please advise if I should delete.

Comment: Up to you. I don't think there will be any answers at this point. I make silly mistakes myself from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

try this


v-for="(item, key) in recommendationResponse[recommendedItems]" 


VueJs v-for works like this, instead of writing "as" we have to write "in"